# Microsoft SQL server using clear text file to store credentials. Can I store the hash of password instead?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hash

I'm currently using SQL server 2008 R2(SP1) and SQL server 2008 (SP3) and the applications using these servers are storing the credentials in a plain text json file. My issue is I need to store user credentials as access is only allowed to authorized users.

How should I go about this? Could I sub out the credentials with the hashed version?

Comment: What applications are you using? Do you have a logon/logoff class?

Comment: jasper reports, ECM, etc. All the applications uses the json file though and yes to logon/logoff class

Answer (score 0):

you can try with:

```
SELECT pwdencrypt('YOURPASSWORDHERE')
```

Comment: This is what I found when I googled `pwdencrypt`    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx

Comment: So do you think it will accept the hashed password instead of the un-hashed password?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'yourpassword');
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', @HashThis);
```